# Get Performance counter for Clustered MSMQ

Tags: c#, msmq, performancecounter

I been trying reading performance counter of a Clustered MSMQ. I've gone through several post to find out a way to read this value and I've seen solution which says that to read counter value one need to create a RegistryKey named as "NetNameForPerfCounters". This is to be created under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MSMQ\PARAMETER\NetNameForPerfCounters and as a value I've specified the network name of my cluster. But all in vain it is not reading anything.

```
var category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("MSMQ Queue", "<Clustered IP>")
Console.WriteLine(category.GetInstanceNames().Count().ToString());
```

This always return count as 0.

Answer (score 0):

You'd think that IP address would work as `machineName`, but I'm not sure it does. I find that using an actual machine name (`"."`, or `"acomputername"`) works but using an IP address fails.

I find the same in PowerShell; using IP fails:

```
Get-Counter -Counter (Get-Counter -ListSet "MSMQ Queue"  -Computer 127.0.0.1 ).PathsWithInstances
```

But the same line with `-computer "machinename"` succeeds and shows my queues.

For larger networks, I think this means you'd need `@"domainname\machinename"`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter

Comment: Yes your powershell script is working with both "IP" & network name of cluster but I want to achieve this "PerformanceCounter with C#"

Comment: So getting the counter from powershell works (with no special permissions?) , but even if you use windows name of cluster instead of "<Clustered IP>" it doesn't work in C# code?

Comment: Is the C# code a commandline exe? If it's hosted in WCF or Asp.Net then it will run under an IIS account with almost no permissions so that would fail

Comment: Yes powershell works with no special permission and it work with both "Network name of cluster" & IP as well. But does not work with C#. I've used PerformanceCounter Class. Code is not giving any error but it is not able to find any instances of MSMQ.

Comment: It is a console application.

Comment: Have you tried checking counters can be read with Performance Monitor? The most common problem I found with monitoring clustered MSMQ was that the queues weren't actually clustered and were instead hosted by on of the local nodes instead.

Comment: As in, the point made here? http://www.winterdom.com/msmq/2011/10/25/using-powershell-with-clustered-msmq.html

Comment: I've given up performance counter from C#. Now I'm going ahead with your solution. But with your solution is it possible to get only message count. The current script given by you is also returning bytes in queue.